# What is the meaning and role of global hyperbolicity condition for semi-Riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

What is the heuristic meaning of the global hyperbolicity condition for semi-Riemannian manifolds?

Also what is the role of this condition in the study of geodesic connectedness?

Comment: The first question is pretty well addressed in the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold , see especially the remarks.  For the second question: the role is very little. There are well known examples (for example de Sitter space) where the manifold is globally hyperbolic but not geodesic-connected.

Comment: As @WillieWong pointed out, a globally hyperbolic semi-Riemannian manifold is not necessarily geodesically connected. However, under additional (geometric) assumptions, it is possible to obtain a positive result: see Candela, A. M.; Flores, J. L.; Sánchez, M., Global hyperbolicity and Palais-Smale condition for action functionals in stationary spacetimes, Adv. Math. 218, No. 2, 515-536 (2008).